# How to play a sound while running in the background?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I need to be  able to play a sound while running the application in the background.

I tried with UILocalNotifications but the file needs to be part of the bundle, and that will not be the case, as I need to generate the sound files on the fly...

So is there any way that I can play a sound while running in the background?

Thanks.

Comment: you need file in app resources.then you can play the sound.

Comment: The problem is that I can't save the generated sounds to the app resources.... because it is generated on the fly.. it can only go into the Docs folder..  not to any of the app bundle folders..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, unless you continuously play audio and have the appropriate audio session category set for your app... then your app doesn't go to sleep, it continues to run (again so long as audio is playing).

This is part of the design limitations of iOS multitasking.

Apple has allowed people to get away with having a continuously looping blank audio file (AVAudioPlayer loop = -1 with a 1-sec blank CAF file) if the app is primarily audio related and it is obvious to the user that this has battery life implications (and can be disabled by the user), but YMMV... you app can also be rejected for this.

Comment: How to avoid to have the play icon in the status bar when blank audio is played ?

Comment: I don't know that you can.

Comment: The Runkeeper app has this feature... and has not been rejected by Apple... How is it possible ?

Comment: Runkeeper uses GPS. Those kinds of apps are not only allowed to run continuously (think map directions), but can speak because the apps often announce directions.